# Cant see 'incomplete applications' on Goolge Dataproc history server

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

When I am running a spark job I can't see it on the history server under the 'incomplete applications' tab and it does not show up until the job is finished. Is there some setting that I need to set to enable jobs to show up there?

Answer (score 1):

Ah it seems the setting was:
'spark:spark.history.fs.gs.outputstream.type' which needs to be set to 'FLUSHABLE_COMPOSITE'

Otherwise it will only write updates when the job is done.